# How can I solve this gitlab ci yaml error ? jobs:test-on-scdf-tasks config contains unknown keys: trigger

Tags: docker, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I was trying to add the file to the docker home directory for login to docker. But, I can not add a file script to the test section.

```
variables:
  DOCKER_AUTH: echo -n "gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN" | base64
  DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG: echo {\"auths\":{\"container-host:port\":{\"auth\":\"$(eval $DOCKER_AUTH)\"}}}

test-on-scdf-tasks:
  extends: .test-on-downstream
  script:
    - mkdir -p $HOME/.docker
    - eval $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG > $HOME/.docker/config.json
  trigger:
    project: example/scdf-tasks
    branch: master
    strategy: depend
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`script` and `trigger` are mutually exclusive. You can only use one OR the other.

If you trigger a pipeline, the job definitions in *that* pipeline control the script. You cannot add any script to it.

If you have a job with a `script:` section, it cannot also have a `trigger:`.